# Get href using xpath + id

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath

I have a list of search results 9 search results from [this site](https://www.costco.com/sofas-sectionals.html) and I'd like to get the href link for each of the items in the search results.

Here is the xpath and selectors of the 1st, 2nd, and 3rd items' links:

```
'//*[@id="search-results"]/div[4]/div/ctl:cache/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/p[4]/a'

#search-results > div.c_408104 > div > ctl:cache > div.product-list.grid > div:nth-child(8) > div > div.thumbnail > div.caption.link-behavior > div.caption > p.description > a


'//*[@id="search-results"]/div[4]/div/ctl:cache/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/p[4]/a'

#search-results > div.c_408104 > div > ctl:cache > div.product-list.grid > div:nth-child(13) > div > div.thumbnail > div.caption.link-behavior > div.caption > p.description > a


'//*[@id="search-results"]/div[4]/div/ctl:cache/div[3]/div[4]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/p[2]/a'

#search-results > div.c_408104 > div > ctl:cache > div.product-list.grid > div:nth-child(14) > div > div.thumbnail > div.caption.link-behavior > div.caption > p.description > a
```

I've tried:

```
browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href]")
```

but this returns all links on the page, not just the search results. I've also tried using the id, but not sure what is the proper syntax.

```
browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="search-results"]//a')
```

Comment: if you can share the site it will help!

Comment: @MosheSlavin the site has been added to the question : https://www.costco.com/sofas-sectionals.html

Comment: I have posted an answer if you have any questions feel free to ask!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is the `attribute="href"` of all the results...

So I'll show you an example:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


url = 'https://www.costco.com/sofas-sectionals.html'

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
browser = webdriver.Chrome("C:\workspace\TalSolutionQA\general_func_class\chromedriver.exe",
                           chrome_options=chrome_options)


browser.get(url)
result_xpath = '//*[@class="caption"]//a'
all_results = browser.find_elements_by_xpath(result_xpath)
for i in all_results:
    print(i.get_attribute('href'))
```

So what I'm doing here is just getting all the elements that I know to have the links and saving them to `all_results`, now in selenium we have a method `get_attribute` to extract the required attribute.

Hope you find this helpful!

Comment: this works for me! It also works for the xpath: '//*[@class="description"]//a' and on firefox. THANK YOU THANK YOU!

Comment: I posted another selenium question I'm hoping you might be able to help with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53601413/python-selenium-find-element-by-class-and-text @Moshe Slavin

Comment: @Mariah Akinbi I see some answers there... I'll take a look again tomorrow... If you have any questions please feel free to contact me!

Comment: the answers helped a lot! Do you have any good resources for learning the syntax of xpath/html?

Comment: @Mariah Akinbi I can't remember now a specific site... But you can Google best practices for selenium xpath... (It's late at night here... I live in Israel... Maybe I'll see something tomorrow at work...)

Comment: If you want me to review a specific xpath you can send it to my email... moshes@ravtech.co.il

Comment: I really appreciate that!