# Python Selenium - Find element by class and text

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I'm trying to paginate through the results of this search: [Becoming Amazon search](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=becoming&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Abecoming). I get a `'NoSuchElementException'..'Unable to locate element: < insert xpath here >`

Here is the html:

```
<div id="pagn" class="pagnHy">
    <span class="pagnLink">
        <a href="/s/ref=sr_pg_2?rh=...">2</a>
    </span>
</div>
```

Here are the xpaths I've tried:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="pagn" and @class="pagnLink" and text()="2"]')

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="pagn" and @class="pagnLink" and text()="2"]')

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='pagn' and @class='pagnLink' and text()[contains(.,'2')]]")

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='pagnLink' and text()='2']")

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='pagnLink' and text()='2']")
```

If I just use `find_element_by_link_text(...)` then sometimes the wrong link will be selected. For example, if the number of reviews is equal to the page number I'm looking for (in this case, 2), then it will select the product with 2 reviews, instead of the page number '2'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to mix attributes and text nodes from different WebElements in the same predicate. You should try to separate them as below:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="pagn"]/span[@class="pagnLink"]/a[text()="2"]')
```

Comment: this works! what are the attributes and text nodes in this example? Do you have any good resources for learning this?

Comment: Attributes in this case are `id` and `class`: nodes that appears *inside* tag e.g. `<tag_name attr_1="foo" attr_2="bar">...</tag_name>`. In XPath you can refer to attributes as `@attr_name` or `attribute:attr_name`. Text node in your case is `"2"` - the  value *outside* tag, e.g. `<tag_name>parent_text_1<child_tag>child_text</child_tag>parent_text_2</tag_name>`. You can use [this cheat sheet](http://www.cheat-sheets.org/saved-copy/Locators_table_1_0_2.pdf) to create well-formed XPath expressions (or CSS-selectors)

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it might be better to take a intermediate step and first to get the element which contains the results.
Afterwards you just search within this element.
Doing it this way you simplify your search terms.

```
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Daps&fieldkeywords=becoming&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Abecoming'
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
resp = driver.get(url)
results_list_object = driver.find_element_by_id('s-results-list-atf')
results = results_list_object.find_elements_by_css_selector('li[id*="result"]')

for number, article in enumerate(results):
    print(">> article %d : %s \n" % (number, article.text))
```

Answer (score 1):

When I look at the markup, I'm seeing the following:

```
<span class="pagnLink">
    <a href="/s/ref=sr_pg_2?rh=...">2</a>
</span>
```

So you want to find a `span` with class `pagnLink` that has a child `a` element with the text `2`, or:

```
'//*[@class="pagnLink"]/a[text()="2"]'
```